# App Icon Not Showing But App is Installed

Tags: android

android studio app icon doesnt appear in the home screen or app list but is present in setting in manage apps. I can force stop it or unistall it but not able to relaunch it.Please help me.

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".First">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FIRST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Second"/>
    <activity android:name=".Team"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Change `FIRST` to `MAIN` if that's your app entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

instead of

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.FIRST"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned wrong `<intent-filter>`

**Change it to**

```
<intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>
```